# attach an existing pdf to a new pdf, using dinktopdf

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, .net-core, dinktopdf

I need to attach an existing pdf to a new pdf, using dinktopdf, I'm trying to use  or  passing both base64 and file location as src, but without success, it generates the page in white, anyone if it is any limitation of the dinktopdf?

Or am I doing something wrong?

This code below that I'm using for testing, thank you if anyone can help.

Obs: run on docker:
[DockerFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EDXg3.png) [csproj config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsiLx.png)

c# code:

Startup > ConfigureServices

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    string wkHtmlToPdfFileName = RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) ? "libwkhtmltox.so" :
                                    RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.OSX) ? "libwkhtmltox.dylib" :
                                        "libwkhtmltox.dll";

    var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
    context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), wkHtmlToPdfFileName));
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
}
```

```
protected IConfigurationGenerateFiles _configFiles;
protected IConverter _converter;

private HtmlToPdfDocument _pdfDocument;
protected List<ObjectSettings> _pages = new List<ObjectSettings>();

public DinkToPdfService(IConfigurationGenerateFiles configFiles,
    IConverter converter)
{
    _configFiles = configFiles;
    _converter = converter;
}

public virtual async Task<byte[]> Generate()
{
    var globalSettings = new GlobalSettings
    {
        Orientation = Orientation.Portrait,
        PaperSize = PaperKind.A4,
    };

    _pdfDocument = new HtmlToPdfDocument()
    {
        GlobalSettings = globalSettings,
    };

    await CreateNewPdfDocumentStreamWithDownload(
        _configFiles._downloadFile,
        "testFileDownload");

    _pdfDocument.Objects.AddRange(_pages);

    return _converter.Convert(_pdfDocument);
}

protected async Task CreateNewPdfDocumentStreamWithDownload(DownloadFile _downloadFile, string fileId)
{
    using (var srcPdfStream = await GetSourcePdfDownloadedStream(_downloadFile, fileId))
    {
        var objectSettings = new ObjectSettings
        {
            PagesCount = true,
            WebSettings = { DefaultEncoding = "utf-8" },
            HtmlContent = HTML_TEST(Convert.ToBase64String(srcPdfStream.ToArray()))
        };

        _pages.Add(objectSettings);
    }
}

private string HTML_TEST(string base64Content) =>
    @$"<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
                <style>
                table, th, td {{
                  border: 1px solid black;
                  border-collapse: collapse;
                  font-family: Helvetica;
                }}
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <iframe 
                    src=""data:application/pdf;base64,{base64Content}"" type='application/pdf'
                    frameBorder='0'
                    scrolling='auto'
                    height='700px'
                    width='100%'> 
                </iframe>
            </body>
        </html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The object settings - HTML Content property is a string. So I assume you have one File and other File is generated from HTML.
So Convert first file(byte array) to string and append to the second HTML string. Then if you convert, it gives you one file with both file contents appended.